# javascript redirecting to main window doesn't take into account http option (&)

Tags: php, javascript, http, redirect

i'm triying to use javascript redirect to main window after log in succeed in an iframe.
this is my code :

```
    if ($_GET['redirect']!='') {
    $redirect=$_GET['redirect'];
    $smart->assign('redirect',$redirect);
}
$redirect=$_GET['redirect'];
echo $redirect;

if(isset ($_SESSION['user'])&&$_SESSION['user']!='') {

    $user->email=$_SESSION['user'];
    $user->addCorporate();
    $user->signIn();
    $user->loadSession();

    echo("<script language=\"javascript\" type=\"text/javascript\">");
    echo "document.write('redirecting...');";

    if ($redirect!='') {
       echo 'self.parent.location = "'.$redirect.'"';
   } else
        echo 'self.parent.location = "index.php"';
     //echo $redirect;

   // redirect($redirect);
    echo "</script>";
}
```

the echo `$redirect` displays `http://xxxxxxxx/play.php?action=play&id=d59541b89828da34e9a8345a1bdafe2b`
but the redirection is made to `http://xxxxxxxx/play.php`? (without the php option)

Comment: btw the thingies that get lost aren't specific to PHP, but to HTTP in general and called URL parameters. Not sure if that's the official title actually but maybe it helps attract people to the question if you call them like that.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds pretty mysterious.
Here's how I'd proceed: Turn off JavaScript in your browser and examine your created JavaScript. Then, at least, you know whether maybe for some bizarre reason the wrong URL is print out after all, or whether the problem's in the redirection part.

Comment: echo 'alert("'.$redirect.'")';
displays xxxxxx/play.php?action=play (without option)

Comment: that's strange. but maybe there's actually in linebreak in your string after the & ? because it also shows as a linebreak in your question (the id begins in a new line).

Answer (score 0):

If you change the line:

```
 echo 'self.parent.location = "'.$redirect.'"';
```

to this:

```
 echo 'alert("'.$redirect.'")';
```

What happens?